# C++ - Basic Tic-Tac-Toe Program prints Blank Screen

Tags: c++, arrays, linux, cout

I'm working on a basic Tic Tac Toe game in C++, as I'm a beginner, but this function prints out a messed up thing, usually either a blank screen or a messed up version of it with odd characters. 
Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void printboard()
{
   std::string array[9] = {"O","O","O","O","O","O","O","O","O"};


   std::cout << "    |     |    " << std::endl;
   std::cout << "  "; std::cout << array[2]; std::cout << "  |  ";                      std::cout << array[4]; std::cout << "   |  "; std::cout << array[3];    std::cout << "  " << std::endl;
   std::cout << "    |     |    " << std::endl;
   std::cout << "----|-----|----" << std::endl;
   std::cout << "  "; std::cout << array[5]; std::cout << "  |  ";            std::cout << array[1]; std::cout << "   |  "; std::cout << array[3];  std::cout << "  " << std::endl;
   std::cout << "    |     |    " << std::endl;
   std::cout << "----|-----|----" << std::endl;
   std::cout << "  "; std::cout << array[7]; std::cout << "  |  ";              std::cout << array[9]; std::cout << "   |  "; std::cout << array[8];    std::cout << "  " << std::endl;
   std::cout << "    |     |    " << std::endl;
   std::cout << "    |     |    " << std::endl;
```

}

Comment: Where's your `main()` function?

Comment: Loops.  Loops will help simplify your code.  Simple code has fewer defects and is easier to debug.

Comment: Arrays are 0 based. `array[9]` is out of bounds. Adjust the index and print will display properly.

Comment: @lorro In a seperate file.

Comment: @alvits You're 100% right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void printboard()
{
    std::string array[9] = { "O","O","O","O","O","O","O","O","O" };

    std::cout << "    |     |    " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "  "; std::cout << array[2]; std::cout << " |  "; std::cout << array[4]; std::cout << "  |  "; std::cout << array[3]; std::cout << "  " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "    |     |    " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "----|-----|----" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "    |     |    " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "  "; std::cout << array[5]; std::cout << " |  "; std::cout << array[1]; std::cout << "  |  "; std::cout << array[3]; std::cout << "  " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "    |     |    " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "----|-----|----" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "    |     |    " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "  "; std::cout << array[7]; std::cout << " |  "; std::cout << array[6]; std::cout << "  |  "; std::cout << array[8]; std::cout << "  " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "    |     |    " << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    printboard();
    std::system("Pause");

    return 0;
}
```

I noticed that your original code referenced [9] of an array of size 9, which is out of bounds (the last entry in that array would be [8]), and you included one too many spaces when aligning your boxes, so the values were skewed a bit. Hope this helps.

Comment: Testing it out now.

Comment: YOU'RE A GENIUS! Thanks so much for the help!